# how to expand a vector of size 2x2 an dummy dimension 2x2x1?

Tags: matlab

How to expand a vector of size 2x2 a dummy dimension 2x2x1? I need a three-dimension vector to put into my function. I have searched online but do not get a solution.

Comment: MATLAB arrays have an infinite number of implicit trailing singleton dimensions. Try `[m,n,k]=size(array)` with your 2x2 array. You’ll see `k=1`!

Comment: To clarify, MATLAB does not physically store trailing singleton dimensions beyond the 2nd dimension in the variable. But MATLAB allows you to treat the variable as if it had those trailing dimensions = 1 when dealing with size and indexing.  E.g., array(2,2) and array(2,2,1) and array(2,2,1,1) all index the same element in MATLAB even though array is a 2x2 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

pass QE, welcome. How about the following:

```
>> a=[1 2;3 4]; b=reshape(a,[1 2 2]); disp(size(b));
     1     2     2

>> disp(b)
(:,:,1) =
     1     3
(:,:,2) =
     2     4
```

If you do `b=reshape(a,[2,2,1]);` then Matlab gives only two dimensions for the size of b.